# 'SEVERE: SAAJ0009: Message send failed error' while sending a message

Tags: java, soap, jaas

```
Feb 8, 2011 11:56:49 AM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPC
onnection post
SEVERE: SAAJ0009: Message send failed
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: java.security.PrivilegedA
ctionException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message s
end failed
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.cal
l(Unknown Source)
        at external.main(external.java:47)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.messagi
ng.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send f
ailed
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.pos
t(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection$Pri
viledgedPost.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown
Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown S
ource)
        ... 5 more

CAUSE:

java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOA
PExceptionImpl: Message send failed
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.cal
l(Unknown Source)
        at external.main(external.java:47)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send f
ailed
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.pos
t(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection$Pri
viledgedPost.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect    
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown
Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown S
ource)
        ... 5 more

CAUSE:


java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOA
PExceptionImpl: Message send failed
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.cal
l(Unknown Source)
        at external.main(external.java:47)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send f
ailed
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.pos
t(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection$Pri
viledgedPost.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown
Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown S
ource)
        ... 5 more
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOA
PExceptionImpl: Message send failed
```

Answer (score 11):

The above problem occurs when there is a PROXY problem occurs. 
There are 2 ways to resolve this. 
I was facing the same problem while creating a SOAP Envelope and calling a web service. 
When I tried testing this request created by my code from SOAP-UI Client, it was working absolutely fine because I have set the proxy, username & password. 
But When I tried to fetch the response by calling the web service from Eclipse code itself, this did not work for me. 
I also tried to set the proxy object within Network Connections tab in Eclipse. 
For this, I changed the initial setting from Native TO Manual & simply added my proxy, username & password. 
But unfortunately, this also did not work for me. 
I then simply added 1 line of code to pick up system set proxy within my code & this has resolved my problem. 
You have to add : System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
This will simply pick up system set proxies within your code & will work fine. 
If this is also not working, your request object has got some problem for sure.

Comment: Where would you add this line of code in the beginning or end?

Answer (score 0):

Exception says :

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

The URL you are trying to access for WebService isn't accessible from your machine.
double check it by ping, is there any proxy settings , firewall . ..etc.

Comment: ya iam working behind the proxy...so what should i do to overcome the proxy..?or how to configure proxy in jaas..?

Comment: it seems you haven't properly proxied your app. contact your network admin